# ASUS Wireless Utility Mac Crashing

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I purchased an ASUS usb wireless device, installed the provided application for my mac pro 10.6.8. I plug in the key, it discovers networks, but when I'm trying to connect to any of them the application just crashes. I contacted ASUS with the problem, however I thought maybe someone here can help decode the apple error report so I can solve this issue and get back online.

Bellow is the error:
http://dumpz.org/200425/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  The only solution I have is to the wps tab and connect via the PBS button, remembering to press the wps button on your router.  This only works if you can actually access the router and would be no use in coffee shops etc.

The device can access open networks - there is clearly a bug in trying to access secure networks.